# how fix order of layers in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie at Unity and I have a problem. When I change the car location, it goes under the background.
The car layer is bigger than the others in the order of layers. How could I fix it?
It's ok in the scene but not in the game section!
[the car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zOEZ.png)

[image: the scene]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_BwFB-1dAo

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html